# Populating Kendo Grid With Search Results MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been working on an application that implements CRUD actions. I am fairly new to Kendo. I have created an observable object, which will allow me to send a whole object to my controller. My controller then gets the object and filters out the client name and then send it to a repo class that calls my database and searches for the user name. Once the results are retrieved in a list, they are sent back to my controller, which then returns it as a JSON object that will be populated my grid. From the Kendo examples and documentation I have created the following code, but the Kendo grid does not seem to populate.

This is My JS/Kendo Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    client: {
        clientName: "",
        clientNumber: "",
        clientType: "",
    },

    dropdownlist: ["HCC", "Tax", "Audit", "Advisory"],

    create: function (e) {
        var userRequest = $("#clientname").val();
        if (userRequest) {
            client.read();
            client.sync();
        }
        if (!userRequest) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please Enter Client Name");
        }
    }
});

kendo.bind($("#engagementForm"), viewModel);

var client = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "Client/SearchClient",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "Client/DeleteClient",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (e) {
                alert("Client Removed");
            }

        },
        update: {
            url: "Client/EditCustomer",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (e) {
                alert("Client Updated");
            }
        },
        create: {
            url: "Client/CreateInformation",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (e) {
                alert("Client Created");
            }
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            switch (operation) {
                case "read":
                    return JSON.stringify(viewModel);
                    break;
                case "create":
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                    break;
                case "update":
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                    break;
                case "destroy":
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                    break;
            }
        }
    },

    schema: {
        data: "list",
        model: {
            id: "clientNumber",

            fields: {
                clientNumber: { type: "int" },
                clientName: { type: "string" },
                clientType: { type: "string" },
            },
        }
    }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "Client/SearchClient",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }
        },

    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [{
        field: "clientNumber",
        title: "Client Number",
    },
    {
        field: "clientName",
        title: "Client Name",
    },
    {

        field: "clientType",
        title: "Client Type",
        editor: function (e) {
            $('<input data-role="dropdownlist" id = "dlist" data-bind="source: dropdownlist , value: clientType">')
            .appendTo(e)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Engagement Types",
                dataSource: viewModel.dropdownlist,
            });
        }
    },
    {
        command: ["edit", "destroy"]
    }],
    editable: "popup",
    edit: function (e) {
        if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
            $('input[name=clientNumber]').parent().html(e.model.clientNumber);
        }
    }
})


});
```

This is my controller that will receive the wanted search from the user:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchClient(ClientInfo client)
{
    Repo repo = new Repo();
    var search = client.clientName; // Just want to get the client name
    repo.SearchClient(search); // Sending Just the Client Name 
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    return Json(new
    {
        list = result,
        //count = result.Count
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my Repo class that will search for the client name:

```
public List<ClientInfo> SearchClient(string clientName)
{
    List<ClientInfo> client = new List<ClientInfo>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE ClientName =@clientName", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", clientName);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ClientInfo data = new ClientInfo();
                    data.clientName = reader["ClientName"].ToString();
                    data.clientNumber = reader["ClientNumber"].ToString();
                    data.clientType = reader["ClientType"].ToString();
                    client.Add(data);
                }                    
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return client;
}
```

**UPDATED 12/21/15 1:50 pm EST**

I have took this approach to simplify things.  This should work but I am getting a 404 error in Fiddler.

My Updated Controller for my problem:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult()
{
    Repo repo = new Repo();
    ClientInfo data = new ClientInfo();
    List<ClientInfo> searchResult = new List<ClientInfo>();
    searchResult = repo.SearchClient(data);
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = searchResult;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchClient(ClientInfo client)
{
    Repo repo = new Repo();
    repo.SearchClient(client);
    return null;

}
```

My updated Kendo Grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({

    dataSource: {

        transport: {
            read: "Client/SearchResult",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "json",
        }
    },

    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [{
        field: "clientNumber",
        title: "Client Number",
    },
    {
        field: "clientName",
        title: "Client Name",
    },
    {

        field: "clientType",
        title: "Client Type",
        editor: function (e) {
            $('<input data-role="dropdownlist" id = "dlist" data-bind="source: dropdownlist , value: clientType">')
            .appendTo(e)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "Engagement Types",
                dataSource: viewModel.dropdownlist,
            });
        }
    },
    {
        command: ["edit", "destroy"]
    }],
    editable: "popup",
    edit: function (e) {
        if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
            $('input[name=clientNumber]').parent().html(e.model.clientNumber);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use razor to create your grid? And, how did you end up with this code by looking at Kendo's examples? Your code doesn't have anything to do with Kendo's examples.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but the company I am working for is wanting to eliminate Razor and Ajax calls.  It is a bummer bow they impose this on the new guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `repo.SearchClient(search)` is returning `List<ClientInfo>` and `result` variable is empty `JsonResult`. Make this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchClient(ClientInfo client)
{
    Repo repo = new Repo();
    var search = client.clientName; // Just want to get the client name
    return Json(new
    {
        list = repo.SearchClient(search),
        //count = result.Count
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying but if i do it your way I am not sending anyt information to my Repo class.

Comment: @EasyE `list = repo.SearchClient(search)` is actually calling `SearchClient` method with paramenter `search`

Comment: Ok this does not seem to be working for me, I went ahead and created another controller to make things easier but seems like I am getting a 404 error in fiddler.  I have updated my code